# create local variable inside v-for

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js

Code snippet

```
<div v-for="item in dataItems">
 <div v-if="enableEdit">
  <input type="text" v-model="name">
 </div>
 <div v-else>
   {{name}}
 </div>
<button @click="enableEdit = true">click</button>
```

This is not working because `enableEdit` is not declared as variable inside script.
Is it possible to create a local variable inside v-for?

Answer (score 1):

Creating a variable inside of template is impossible as far as I know, but you can achieve the same effect by doing the following.

Edit your template:

```
  <div v-for="item in dataItems" :key="item.id">
    <div v-if="editedElementId !== item.id" @click="editItem(item.id)">
      {{item.name}}
    </div>
    <div v-else>
     <input type="text" placeholder="New name..." v-model="item.name" />
    </div>
  </div>
```

Remember to always use `:key` with `v-for`.

Then add `editedElementId: null` inside of `data` and a new method `editItem`:

```
  methods: {
    editItem(id) {
        this.editedElementId = id
    }
  }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/eywraw8t/317760/

Answer (score 0):

Handling the undefined, you can generate a field name that is specific for the actual for loop:

```
<div v-for="(month, mi) in months" :key="mi">
    <div v-for="(day, di) in days" :key="di">
     ... <div v-if="generated_fields['month_' + mi + '_day_' + di]">
        ... <here_you_can_use> generated_fields['month_' + mi + '_day_' + di] ...
...
data:function(){
    return{
        ...
        generated_fields:{}//for fields starts undefined, autofills when written
        ...
}
```